# On the Euclidean action for QCD

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conventions, quantum-chromodynamics, dirac-matrices, wick-rotation

The Euclidean action for QCD reads, (see e.g., Eq. (45) in "[ABC](https://doi.org/10.1070/PU1982v025n04ABEH004533) of [instantons](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812798961_0003)" by Novikov, Shifman, Vainshtein, and Zakharov)
$$S_E=\int d^4 x\left[\frac{1}{4}G^a_{\mu\nu}G^a_{\mu\nu}+\psi^\dagger(-i\gamma_\mu D_\mu-im)\psi\right].\tag{45}$$
Here $\gamma_\mu$ are gamma matrices in Euclidean space, i.e., $\{\gamma_\mu,\gamma_\nu\}=2\delta_{\mu\nu}$. Sometimes, people also use the notation $\bar\psi$ to replace the above $\psi^\dagger$.

Now, we know that the operator $-i\gamma_\mu D_\mu$ is hermitian but $-im$ is not (actually it is anti-hermitian). Then the fluctuation operator as a whole, $-i\gamma_\mu D_\mu -i m$ is not hermitian. Won't this be a problem? For instance, the eigenvalues for this operator are in general complex.

How do people treat this in,for instance, lattice QCD?

Comment: By the way, $\psi^\dagger$ is distinct from $\bar \psi = \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$ which is important for Lorentz invariance of the action.

Comment: @lux Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am aware of the difference between $\psi^\dagger$ and $\bar\psi$ in Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: Are you saying you have chosen a rep of the euclidean gamma matrices such that \gamma^0$ is the identity?

Comment: @lux No, there is no basis that $\gamma_0$ can be the identity, otherwise you will have $\{\gamma_0,\gamma_i\}\neq 0$. It is because $\bar\psi$ behaves like $\psi^\dagger$ under $SO(4)$ and this is due to $\gamma_\mu^\dagger=\gamma_\mu$ in Euclidean space while in Minkowski we have $(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger=\gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \gamma^0$.

Comment: With the Euclidean action it does not matter whether the Lagrangian is Hermitian or anti-Hermitian, but only whether it is bounded below: the path integral is something like $\int e^{-S_E}$ (there is no $i$ in the exponent). If the fermionic part of the action is purely imaginary, then it is bounded by definition (but I find this a bit surprising, to be honest...)

Comment: This is weird notation I think; note the $-i$ in eq. (44). When you evaluate your path integral, this factor will also be in the measure, so in the end you're always just taking the determinant of a hermitian matrix. This isn't my field so I really have no idea why someone would want to define $\bar{\psi}$ in such a way in the first place (though the books I have certainly do not do this).

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing something due to the notation used in that article. In Lorentzian signature the quantity $\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \psi$ is a scalar. Going to Euclidean signature with $\gamma_0 = \gamma_4$, we have that $\psi^\dagger \gamma_4 \psi$ is again a scalar. However, note that the paper defines a new quantity see Equation (44) to distinguish the Euclidean space quantities from Lorentzian quantities:

$$ \hat{\bar\psi} = i \bar \psi = i \psi^\dagger \gamma_4 \qquad \hat \psi = \psi $$

Hence,

$$ \bar \psi \psi = -i \hat{\bar \psi} \hat \psi   \implies (-i) \times \hat{\bar \psi} \hat \psi  = \bar \psi \psi \quad \text{ is hermitian}$$

However, the easiest answer the question is that in Equation (45) they establish the relationship between the Euclidean and the Lorentzian Lagrangian. Since the Lorentzian Lagrangian is hermitian so must be the Euclidean one since by definition $\mathcal{L}_E$ is constructed from $\mathcal{L}_L$ by sprinkling $i$'s so that schematically

$$ \mathcal{L}_E[\phi_E] = \mathcal{L}_L[\phi_L]$$